# Return the day of yesterday if a cell is updated after midnight

Tags: google-sheets, autocomplete, filenames

In a google sheets document I implemented a script where the Sheet name is changed based on the content in cell A10.
This is the script:

```
function onEdit() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var oldName = sheet.getName();
  var newName = sheet.getRange(1,10).getValue();
  if (newName.toString().length>0 && newName !== oldName) {
    sheet.setName(newName);
  }
}
```

In cell A10 I have the formula =concatenate(A1:A9).
In A1 I have the formula =day(today()). A2 = month(today()). A3 = year(today()). Then some static text in the next cells and in A9 is the input that will trigger the filename to be changed.

In this way, the sheet name is changed automatically with the current day, month, year, based on the time when the A9 cell content is changed.

I have 3 sheets, that are changed in the morning, afternoon and night. With the morning and afternoon sheets, there is no problem, but for the night, because it can be changed either before or after midnight, I would like to use the same day as the other 2 sheets, no matter the time when it is changed.

I already tried this formula for the day cell in the night sheet, but without success:

```
A1=if(day(today)='Afternoon'!A1; day(today()) ; day((today())-1))
```

Is there a way how to refine this formula, or should I take a different approach?

Thank you!

Comment: `I would like to use the same day as the other 2 sheets` `Day` is not the only issue; one day can change both the _month_  and the _year_. Are these issues in your scenario? Would you also clarify whether there is **any** information on a given sheet that identifies it as morning, afternoon or night?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Evening Day Value

```
=LET(now, NOW(),
   DAY(now-(MOD(now, 24)<12)))
```

- Subtracts 1 day if the time is before 12:00 PM (noon).
- Since **`1 day=1`** and **`1 hour=1/24`** it follows that **`MOD(x, 24)=12`** where **`x=12:00 PM`**

## Single Date String Formulas

As @Tedinoz pointed out, addressing the day in the absence of the date, is prone to errors with the day, the month, and the year:

- **`DAY("1/1/23")-1 ≠ DAY("1/1/23"-1)`**
- **`MONTH("1/1/23") ≠ MONTH("1/1/23"-1)`**
- **`YEAR("1/1/23")  ≠ YEAR("1/1/23"-1)`**

The three sheets should each use a single formula to return the date string.

### Evening Date String

```
=LET(now, NOW(),
   TEXT(
     now-(MOD(now, 24)<12), 
     "ddmmyyyy"))
```

- Replaces the three formulas in **`A1:A3`**.
- Tweak the date string format as you prefer.

### Morning/Afternoon Date String

```
=TEXT(NOW(), "ddmmyyyy")
```

- Replaces the three formulas in **`A1:A3`**.
- Strips off the time using a single date format.
- Tweak date string format as you prefer.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your extensive response.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your response. I changed the formulas for the evening and afternoon to get rid of the three formulas. It is a better idea, even more that the file is all the time changed during current day. But for the evening/night, I have a question. The time-frame when the file can be changed is between 21:00 and 05:00. Am I judging correctly that if I change in your first formula 12 with 5, the 1 day substraction will happen only when the file is changed before 05:00? Also, is the same formula legit if I change DAY with MONTH/YEAR and use them for the month and year as well?

Comment: Also your Evening Date String formula is missing a ( after TEXT.

Comment: @CatalinCiobanu Yes, the formula is legit for DAY/MONTH/YEAR.. Yes, you would change 12 to 5 as suggested. Also, if the time frame *includes* 5:00 then change `<12` to `<=5`.  Ty for catching the typo, I corrected it by moving a closing parenthesis that was originally after the  TEXT function's `number` argument to where it should have been, after  its `format` argument.

Comment: @CatalinCiobanu I apologize that I didn't catch that your locale uses `, ` as decimal sepperator.  Obviously you knew to switch `,` for `;` in the formulas. Oops!

Comment: Yeah, I figured out fast about the , and ;